# How to refer a file in Google Colab when working with Python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have to work with exporting Google Auth credentials when working on a Google Colab notebook.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='[PATH_TO_CREDS.JSON]'
```

When I refer to the local file like "/Users/user/file", it is not able to be found and getting the error as below.

> DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine
>   credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly
>   create credential and re-run the application

How do I make the path work, so colab can pick it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a way to make local files work, but I found mounting Google Drive convenient and it worked. I placed the file on a temp folder in Colab Notebooks folder of Google Drive where I saved all my Colab files.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

#ensure the file is accessible
!ls /content/gdrive/'My Drive'/'Colab Notebooks'/temp

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/temp/b08d5871a151.json"

#ensure the path is set correctly
!echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```